# Rancher desktop error when starting kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rancher-desktop

My Rancher desktop was working just fine, until today when I switched container runtime from containerd to dockerd. When I wanted to change it back to containerd, it says:

```
Error Starting Kubernetes
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
```

Some recent logfile lines:

```
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBFQyBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tCk1IY0NBUUVFSUV1eXhYdFYvTDZOQmZsZVV0Mnp5ekhNUmlzK2xXRzUxUzBlWklKMmZ5MHJvQW9HQ0NxR1NNNDkKQXdFSG9VUURRZ0FFNGdQODBWNllIVzBMSW13Q3lBT2RWT1FzeGNhcnlsWU8zMm1YUFNvQ2Z2aTBvL29UcklMSApCV2NZdUt3VnVuK1liS3hEb0VackdvbTJ2bFJTWkZUZTZ3PT0KLS0tLS1FTkQgRUMgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQo=

2022-09-02T13:03:15.834Z: Error starting lima: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12) {
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE'
}
```

Tried reinstalling, factory reset etc. but no luck. I am using 1.24.4 verison.

Comment: I just got the same error, did you solved it (:

Comment: No, sadly no, I stopped using it after that.

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR: Try turning off Docker/Something that is binding to port 6443.** Reset Kubernetes in Rancher Desktop, then try again.

Try checking if there is anything else listening on port 6443 which is needed by kubernetes:rancher-desktop.

In my case, `lsof -i :6443` gave me...

```
 ~ lsof -i :6443                           
COMMAND     PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 63385 ~~~~~~~~~~~~  150u  IPv4 0x44822db677e8e087      0t0  TCP localhost:sun-sr-https (LISTEN)
ssh       82481 ~~~~~~~~~~~~   27u  IPv4 0x44822db677ebb1e7      0t0  TCP *:sun-sr-https (LISTEN)
```